# UILabel taking space when number of lines is fixed in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a **UILabel** in **UITableViewCell**.I have given it's constraints as Top,Bottom,Leading ,Trailing. If I give it numberoflines as 0 then it does not take any space.But if  give it fix number of lines then it takes extra space from top & bottom. Please tell me what is the issue ?

Code for UITableView Delegates

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

Constraints Given as

[image]

Screenshot for the **UITableViewCell**

[image]

Comment: show your code, both data source methods for the tableView, and design code for cell

Comment: like Milan said, provide more information for your problem

Comment: in `estimatedHeightForRowAt` return a constant, eg: 44, not `UITableViewAutomaticDimension `

Comment: Return some number in estimatedHeightForRowAt method.

Comment: Others label have number of lines how much?

Comment: First has zero,second has one,third is 3 & rest have 1

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: You have added one screenshot what else you have updated ?

Answer (score 0):

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let lbl = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(10) as! UILabel
    lbl.text = "abcljfdslkfj;dlskfjd;slkfjds;ljdsfldjsf;ldsjfdslkfjds;lfjds;lfjdfl;jdsf;lkdjsf;ldsjf;ldskjd;slfjdsl;fjd;fljdfl;kjsdflljksdabcljfdslkfj;dlskfjd;slkfjds;ljdsfldjsf;ldsjfdslkfjds;lfjds;lfjdfl;jdsf;lkdjsf;ldsjf;ldskjd;slfjdsl;fjd;fljdfl;kjsdflljksdabcljfdslkfj;dlskfjd;slkfjds;ljdsfldjsf;ldsjfdslkfjds;lfjds;lfjdfl;jdsf;lkdjsf;ldsjf;ldskjd;slfjdsl;fjd;fljdfl;kjsdflljksdabcljfdslkfj;dlskfjd;slkfjds;ljdsfldjsf;ldsjfdslkfjds;lfjds;lfjdfl;jdsf;lkdjsf;ldsjf;ldskjd;slfjdsl;fjd;fljdfl;kjsdflljksdabcljfdslkfj;dlskfjd;slkfjds;ljdsfldjsf;ldsjfdslkfjds;lfjds;lfjdfl;jdsf;lkdjsf;ldsjf;ldskjd;slfjdsl;fjd;fljdfl;kjsdflljksdabcljfdslkfj;dlskfjd;slkfjds;ljdsfldjsf;ldsjfdslkfjds;lfjds;lfjdfl;jdsf;lkdjsf;ldsjf;ldskjd;slfjdsl;fjd;fljdfl;kjsdflljksdabcljfdslkfj;dlskfjd;slkfjds;ljdsfldjsf;ldsjfdslkfjds;lfjds;lfjdfl;jdsf;lkdjsf;ldsjf;ldskjd;slfjdsl;fjd;fljdfl;kjsdflljksdabcljfdslkfj;dlskfjd;slkfjds;ljdsfldjsf;ldsjfdslkfjds;lfjds;lfjdfl;jdsf;lkdjsf;ldsjf;ldskjd;slfjdsl;fjd;fljdfl;kjsdflljksdabcljfdslkfj;dlskfjd;slkfjds;ljdsfldjsf;ldsjfdslkfjds;lfjds;lfjdfl;jdsf;lkdjsf;ldsjf;ldskjd;slfjdsl;fjd;fljdfl;kjsdflljksdabcljfdslkfj;dlskfjd;slkfjds;ljdsfldjsf;ldsjfdslkfjds;lfjds;lfjdfl;jdsf;lkdjsf;ldsjf;ldskjd;slfjdsl;fjd;fljdfl;kjsdflljksdabcljfdslkfj;dlskfjd;slkfjds;ljdsfldjsf;ldsjfdslkfjds;lfjds;lfjdfl;jdsf;lkdjsf;ldsjf;ldskjd;slfjdsl;fjd;fljdfl;kjsdflljksdabcljfdslkfj;dlskfjd;slkfjds;ljdsfldjsf;ldsjfdslkfjds;lfjds;lfjdfl;jdsf;lkdjsf;ldsjf;ldskjd;slfjdsl;fjd;fljdfl;kjsdflljksdabcljfdslkfj;dlskfjd;slkfjds;ljdsfldjsf;ldsjfdslkfjds;lfjds;lfjdfl;jdsf;lkdjsf;ldsjf;ldskjd;slfjdsl;fjd;fljdfl;kjsdflljksdabcljfdslkfj;dlskfjd;slkfjds;ljdsfldjsf;ldsjfdslkfjds;lfjds;lfjdfl;jdsf;lkdjsf;ldsjf;ldskjd;slfjdsl;fjd;fljdfl;kjsdflljksdabcljfdslkfj;dlskfjd;slkfjds;ljdsfldjsf;ldsjfdslkfjds;lfjds;lfjdfl;jdsf;lkdjsf;ldsjf;ldskjd;slfjdsl;fjd;fljdfl;kjsdflljksd"
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually I have labels above & below the current label

Comment: please share screenshot of storyboard with constraints.

Comment: I have shared the screenshot please check

Comment: Can you tell me please what is the issue ?

Comment: I am not able to understand constraints

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/160527/auto-layout-tutorial-ios-11-getting-started Please learn from here.

Comment: I mean I am not able to understand constrains in your screenshot although I know how to apply constraints.

Answer (score 0):

When you give number of lines 0 along with the above constraints, the UILabel will have auto height, which means the AutomaticDimension for tableview cell will height relative to UILabel. When UILabel's text is empty, it's height becomes zero.

To overcome this situation, you can specify either of two things:

1. Minimum height for the UILabel (e.g. in the constraint give height > 30)
2. Estimated height for UITableViewCell using delegate method

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

       return 100

   }
   ```